# Why does this SPARQL query give wrong results?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I tried doing some sparql requests on http://dbpedia.org/sparql.

My sparql-request is this:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?Name ?Todestag ?person 
WHERE {
  ?person dbo:deathPlace :Hamburg .
  ?person foaf:name ?Name .
  ?person dbo:deathDate ?Todestag .
  FILTER ( ?Todestag > "2016-01-01"^^xsd:date ) . 
} ORDER BY ?Todestag
```

The problem:
Somehow this `FILTER` doesn’t work. The SPARQL request gives me all people who died on every day since the start of time in DBpedia. However, I just want people who died after 2016. Can anyone spot the mistake in the query or the syntax?

Comment: The problem is maybe/probably the illegal data itself, i.e. the date literals do not follow the `xsd:date` syntax, are just invalid. For example, `"1415-1-1"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date>` is not allowed. It's a known issue with DBpedia, known for ages I'd say, but seems like nobody cares about or wants to fix it. Or the data comparison just doesn't work, which I do not believe.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm sure the comparison with an illegal literal leads to a `FALSE` in the `FILTER`. For example, this returns something: `SELECT ?Todestag ?person WHERE { 
VALUES (?person ?Todestag) {
(<http://ex.org/person3> "2017-10-10"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date>)
}
FILTER (?Todestag > "2016-01-01"^^xsd:date) . 
} ` while this doesn't:`SELECT ?Todestag ?person WHERE { 
VALUES (?person ?Todestag) {

(<http://ex.org/person3> "2017-1-1"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date>)
}
FILTER (?Todestag > "2016-01-01"^^xsd:date) . 
} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself. The problem is definitely the filter. I have now changed the filter and the desired result appears. The filter must be: `FILTER (str(?Todestag) >= "2016") .`

Completely, it would look like this:

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

SELECT ?Name ?Todestag ?person  
WHERE {       
?person dbo:deathPlace :Hamburg . 
?person foaf:name ?Name . 
?person dbo:deathDate ?Todestag .
FILTER (str(?Todestag) >= "2016") .   
} ORDER BY ?Todestag
```

Comment: That is clearly a wrong answer. While I agree that there is some problem with the FILTER on date literals, you FILTER doesn't make nay sense. ow you do lexical comparison, which is obviously incorrect for date values. That is semantically incorrect. And please check the result of your query...I mean Pope Benedict and `"965-7-4"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date>` ? that is clearly wrong, right? You should ask the Virtuoso devs here for support. Your initial query was already correct, and given that it's homework it's not your fault that it doesn't work as expected

Comment: If all xsd:date literals in the dataset were valid, then lexicographical comparison would work fine here, because in xsd:date, lexicographical order matches date order (for years 0-9999).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct solution to the query, note the casting applied to the FILTER CLAUSE ( i.e. xsd:date(?Todestag ) :

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?Name ?Todestag ?person 
WHERE {
  ?person dbo:deathPlace :Hamburg .
  ?person foaf:name ?Name .
  ?person dbo:deathDate ?Todestag .
  FILTER ( xsd:date(?Todestag) > "2016-01-01"^^xsd:date ) . 
} ORDER BY ?Todestag
```

- [Live Query Solution Page](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3FName%20%3FTodestag%20%3Fperson%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20dbo%3AdeathPlace%20%3AHamburg%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20foaf%3Aname%20%3FName%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20dbo%3AdeathDate%20%3FTodestag%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20xsd%3Adate%28%3FTodestag%29%20%3E%20%222016-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%20%29%20.%20%0D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3FTodestag&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) (format HTML Table).
- [Query Definition Page](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3FName%20%3FTodestag%20%3Fperson%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20dbo%3AdeathPlace%20%3AHamburg%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20foaf%3Aname%20%3FName%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20dbo%3AdeathDate%20%3FTodestag%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20xsd%3Adate%28%3FTodestag%29%20%3E%20%222016-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%20%29%20.%20%0D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3FTodestag&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)